Nuxt 3 website with MSAL pop-up authentication not working in production but works on localhost
I have a Nuxt 3 website that uses MSAL for authentication. When I'm using localhost I'm able to authenticate and use the website like its supposed to. Once deploying to a production environment, all I get is a pop-up with about:blank after clicking the sign in button.
I've tried changing the login URL from the MSAL documentation.
I followed this website article to setup MSAL. https://medium.com/simform-engineering/authentication-with-msal-in-nuxt3-e6ccc110c3d8

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
